# Pass Username to Git Command

Tags: git, batch-file, command-prompt, git-pull

I have a .bat file to preform a git pull for one of my repos, and when I execute the file I have to type in my username and password. I was wondering if there was a way to pass in my username so I only had to type my password.

Below is what my current batch file looks like:

```
cd %HOMEPATH%\Documents\Git\Java
git pull origin
pause
```

Comment: Actually this depends on the remote. Likely, your repository is configured to use `http://` repository as origin.

Comment: I am using GitLab. I can use https or ssh. I am using https though..

Comment: I'd suggest to switch to ssh:// with key-authentication, so that you won't need to type anything. But even with https:// you may specify credentials, see https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials

Comment: I actually just found that site, but do you have to give it a password?

Comment: Well, with ssh key authentication you may use passphrase-less keys or set up a SSH agent which can cache passphrase for a given period of time or for a session. Regarding https authentication I don't have enough experience. Likely, it's possible to setup a tool for credential manipulations.

Comment: With "https" you can use the "~/.netrc" file to configure the autologin information. More info: run "man netrc"

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira: According to the man page on my system, `.netrc` is used for ftp, not https.

Comment: Don't worry, it'll work with https too. Put the following line: "machine <machine> login <username> password <password>" and do not forget to set "chmod 600 .netrc".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use https and you only want to input your password, you can add your username to the repo url. You can run

```
git remote set-url origin https://username@gitlab.example.com/example/some-repo.git
```

to change the repo url.

Or, you can use ssh authentication like others suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ssh authentication it should be solved: http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html